# Hitting time for Brownian motion with upper reflecting boundary

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stopping-times

I was wondering if there exist a known distribution function or a nice closed form describing the first hitting time to a given threshold $a$, $T_a$, for a Brownian motion bounded by a upper reflecting barrier at $b$, with $a<b$ and starting from an initial value $c$, $a<c<b$. Any hints, reference, or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: In the book of Borodin Salminem, Handbook of Brownian Motion, you can find the Laplace transform in Chapter 3, eq 2.0.1. and the density just below.